# Why is setInterval only displaying one of my canvas animations?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am new to using canvas and I am having trouble getting two bouncing ball animations to run. I am using setInterval and have set up my code to resemble the way people say works best:

```
function bCircle() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(bx, by, bRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    c.strokeStyle = "cornflowerblue";
    c.stroke();
    c.fillStyle = "cornflowerblue";
    c.fill();
    c.closePath();

}

function rCircle() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(rx, ry, rRadius, 0, Math.Pi * 2, false);
    c.strokeStyle = "red";
    c.stroke();
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fill();
    c.closePath();

}

function draw() {
    c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
    bCircle();
    rCircle();

    //bCircle Conditional
    if (bx + bRadius > innerWidth || bx - bRadius < 0) {
        bbdx = -bbdx;
    }
    //Conditional to mall the ball bounce up and down
    if (by + bRadius > innerHeight || by - bRadius < 0) {
        bbdy = -bbdy;
    }
    //Add 1 to x continously for it to move
    bx += bbdx;
    //Add 1 constantly to y for it to move up and down also
    by += bbdy;

    //rCircle Conditional
    if (rx + rRadius > innerWidth || rx - rRadius < 0) {
        rrdx = -rrdx;
    }
    if (ry + rRadius > innerHeight || ry - rRadius < 0) {
        rrdy = -rrdy;
    }
    rx += rrdx;
    ry += rrdy;
}



setInterval(function() {
    draw();
}, 8);
```

The problem is that only the blue ball runs no matter what methods I try. Also, if I try and run the red ball function by itself, nothing shows up. I don't know what the issue is because the functions are identical except for the style and fill. No errors ever show up on the console. Can anyone spot what it is I'm missing?

Comment: Can you put this in a snippet, including all your various globals?  I see nothing apparent in the code as shown.

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if you post an example people can run. People here call this a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is, there are a bunch of required variables that we will need to guess just to make this run. Having said that, you should check `Math.PI` in you `rCircle` definition --  `PI` needs to be upper case.

Comment: It was the lowercase PI!! That was two weeks of pouring over this for hours. Thank you so much :) Do you see anything I can do to make the code more efficient?

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16, Are you still facing issue ? or your problem solve ?

Comment: The program works now.